# WooCommerce change default settings for download limit

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, settings

I'm using Wordpress with a WooCommerce plugin. I'm using mostly downloadable product but I'd like that user can only download it once.

There is a settings for download limit of downloadable products, but by default this limit is infinite.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFL7d.png)

How can I change the WooCommerce settings so that this limit is by default "1" or any other number?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding these lines of code to

woocommerce/included/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php

```
public function set_download_limit( $download_limit ) {
        $this->set_prop( 'download_limit', -1 === (int) $download_limit || '' === $download_limit ? -1 : absint( $download_limit ) );
    }
```